# Preciso usar session_generate_id em todas as paginas?

Tags: php, session, segurança

Galera conheci essa função recentemente, eu sei que ela gera outra id aleatoria para a sessão, mas minha dúvida é a seguinte, posso usar essa função uma única vez no caso apos realizar login, e nas outras paginas eu não preciso mais usar ? já vai estar "segura" minha sessão ?

Comment: a finalidade é evitar roubo de sessão

Comment: Acho um jeito meio bobo de evitar roubo de sessão. Pra "roubarem" a sessão, primeiro você precisa trafegar sem HTTPS, e alguém estar monitorando. Se você fica mudando o ID, o próprio usuário pode ter problema com várias abas abertas etc - Eu acho mais interessante fazer um controle separado. Mas qualquer aplicação mais séria vai usar HTTPS, e fica sem sentido gerar novo ID dessa forma. Eu acho mais interessante se você usar isso para renovar sessão, por exemplo, para evitar timeout por causa do cookie. Se a pessoa tem a tecnologia pra roubar o ID velho, ela vê o novo passando da mesma forma.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação do PHP em [**Sessões e segurança**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.security.php):

> Executar a função session_regenerate_id() poderia resultar em ataque DoS, da mesma forma que use_strict_mode=On. No entanto, DoS ainda é melhor do que uma conta exposta. **ID de sessão deve ser renovado pelo menos quando o usuário fizer a autenticação.** A renovação do ID de sessão reduz o risco do roubo de ID de sessão, deste modo ela deve ser executada periodicamente. O desenvolvedor não deve depender da expiração do ID de sessão. Atacantes podem acessar o ID de sessão da vítima periodicamente para impedir que ele expire. Desenvolvedores devem implementar seus próprios meios de expiração para sessões antigas.

Veja que o texto fala: pelo menos uma vez, não quer dizer que você não possa fazer a cada página.

Você deve analisar a situação que está utilizando e o tempo que suas seções ficam abertas.

Por exemplo: em um sistema que mantenho, onde as seções permanecem durante muito tempo, eu chamo o método `session_regenerate_id()` toda vez que um script PHP é chamado.

Em outras situações, você pode definir usar na autenticação.

Comment: pode não ser a melhor alternativa, mas neste caso pretendo gerar uma nova sessão a cada hora, ou ate mesmo a cada 24 horas, você acha plausivel ?

Comment: @OtavioFagundes, porque a cada 24h? Um usuário vai ficar tanto tempo assim? neste caso, não bastaria fazer isso no login? Tenho aplicações rodando a uns 4 anos com o regenerate junto com o session_start em todas as páginas. Funciona sem problemas.

Comment: O cara acima disse: "Se você fica mudando o ID, o próprio usuário pode ter problema com várias abas abertas etc", isso acabou me deixando um pouco confuso

Comment: @OtavioFagundes, recomendo que você implemente e teste. Eu utilizo várias abas do mesmo sistema sem problemas, e além disso, outras abas com outros sistemas no mesmo servidor e tudo sem problema algum.

Comment: vou fazer da mesma forma que vc usa, obrigado!

Comment: Considere utilizar o HTTPS como exposto pelo Bacco. HTTPS é muito importante para a segurança.

Comment: sim vou utilizar, mas vou usar o generate para tratar a sessão também